# GCP Console "cloud-resource-manager" is hidden (not directly navigatable. Are there other pages like this?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I noticed that "cloud-resource-manager" seems to be a page outside of the console's left hand side-bar navigation, and requires a direct URL jump. When I jump directly to [cloud-resource-manager](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager), there is no sidebar, just the top navigation icon. It would indicate that it is a feature outside of the standard GCP workflow, given that actions like `gcloud alpha resource-manager folders create` are denoted as *alpha*.

Are there other pages that don't have a console navigation method? If so can somebody list some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell most GCP products have a link in the [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) even though the links might lead to a separate domain or url. A typical example would be Stackdriver (domain: https://app.google.stackdriver.com), it used to exist outside GCP products domain but just recently it has been integrated with the console ( https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring)

Cloud resource manager has a link in the console as well, you will find it under `"IAM & admin" ==> "Manage resources"` in the left pane. If you don't see list of organizations or projects, it could be due to permission issues. Also make sure the service `cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com` is enabled.

With the latest version of gcloud sdk, version `277.0.0` as of now, folder creation with gcloud is `GA`

```
$ gcloud version 
Google Cloud SDK 277.0.0

$ gcloud resource-manager folders create --help
NAME
    gcloud resource-manager folders create - create a new folder
...
```

Comment: You are quite correct, I would have expected a sub-folder of `/iam-admin/` so I didn't see that, also it appears that the google docs need updating for the GA version. Thanks!